# Use Sqlite Database in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, sqlite, eclipse-plugin

I want to access a SQLite database in my eclipse plugin. Therefore I downloaded the jar file sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar, added it to my project and in the MANIFEST.MF file, I added the jar file to the classpath. Then in my code I do the following in the private constructor:

```
private SQLLiteExporter() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Can't write JDBC driver!");
        }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DATABASE_NAME);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Can't connect to database");
        }
}
```

The problem is, every time when `Class.forName()` is called, a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. I have no clue why. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have correctly added the entry in the Mainfest file.

```
Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/poi-3.6-20091214.jar
```

The classpath can also be set via the *plugin.xml* file, from 'Runtime' tab. See below:

[image: class path]